# What's the best way to parallelize a REST call?

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, java-stream

I'm working on some java code, which processes multiple REST calls

```
call1()
call2()
call3()
...
```

I want to parallelize these calls, but perform my main code synchronously.
I made a POC with lamba and a parallel stream:

```
List<Runnable> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(() -> {call1()});
list.add(() -> {call2()});
list.add(() -> {call3()});
list.add(...);

list.parallelStream()
            .forEach(Runnable::run);
```

Do you have another solution?
I also checked to use async calls from Jersey client instead, but this would need more code changes.

Comment: Does "best", in what you're looking for, means "with the least amount of code" ? One could argue that "blocking the lowest number of threads while finishing in the same amount of time" to be a sensible way of having a better result. So what is "better" to you ?

Comment: Best mean best performance with correct readability and less change in core code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All you're looking for is to run your calls asynchronously. You can use `CompletableFuture`s to submit the task, and then wait for them to complete:

```
list.stream() //you don't really need a parallel stream
    .map(CompletableFuture::runAsync)
    .collect(Collectors.toList()) //make sure all tasks are submitted
    .stream()
    .forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
```

This will submit all tasks (to run asynchronously), and then wait for each of them to finish running. When that happens, the method will return.

You may need to control the thread pool for your async tasks. This is an example using a 10-thread pool:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
list.stream()
    .map(r -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(r, es))
     ...
```

Comment: Although functionally correct (+1), this is not very intelligent from exception safety point of view (specifically thrown from within `CompletableFuture.join()`).

Comment: @bobah Your point regarding exception handling is valid, thanks. That will need to be taken care of. I only included an outline of the solution. As the the code in the question is using `Runnable`, I presumed that the result isn't necessary, but the point is to wait for the call to complete (and I skipped all typical
 result checks)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why are you recommending CompletableFuture over parallel stream?

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin My comment is really not a question of completable future vs parallel stream. I mean that when calls are made asynchronously as in my post, then a parallel stream is not needed. In this case, performance is gained more by the parallelism of task execution (thread pool used to execute tasks), rather than by the parallelism of task submission (parallel stream).

Comment: I'm under the impression (not having read enough to confirm), that parallel streams work on the default ForkJoin pool, as would CompletableFuture `runAsync` tasks (no other arguments). In which case, performance would probably be "on par" with both methods, unless one specifies an explicit thread pool. Right ?

Comment: @ernest_k i don't understand why you will get more performance with parallelism of task execution, i was thinkg that paralelle stream use also thread pool and then the result will be the same

Comment: @GPI I believe so (and that's why I mentioned that explicitly using a custom thread pool may need to be considered).

Comment: @BertrandCedric : one can "assume" that your external REST call is probably not CPU bound :  a given thread will actually need few CPU cycles, and be idle (waiting for the response). For example: **imagine** a call takes 100ms. 90ms will be spent with your thread idle, 10ms will be spent doing real computation (JSON serialization and the like). So for a single CPU second, you could have 100 threads active (100 thread * 10ms = 1 sec) and not actually waste time. If you have or 8 threads, your CPU will work 8*10ms = 80ms and wait for the 920 other ms. This is fictionnal, but you get the idea.

Comment: @BertrandCedric The stream is just submitting tasks. If the task is executed synchronously, then there's no difference. But for asynchronous tasks, task submission (using the fork-join pool in this example) may use more parallelism than task execution (say, a single-thread pool). It seems obvious to me that a service call (or other typical tasks) will normally take longer than it takes to submit them to an executor service (hence, parallelism of execution is more consequential than parallelism of submission).

Comment: Mind the existence of `ExecutorService.invokeAll`. It expects `Callable` instead of `Runnable`, but normally, such operations have a result anyway.