# CompletableFuture grouped by groups of requests

Tags: java, asynchronous, parallel-processing, completable-future

I'd like to send 100K requests to an API Rest. So I have a loop and I send a request in a sync way (and it takes some minutes to complete all requests).

But it's better to send them in an async way, so the process can takes less time because the destination can scale their replicas.

I've read about CompletableFuture and how to combine all results with `allOf()` method.

But is there any way to make the calls in groups of 1K requests? Because If I send all the requests in parallel, the destination close the connection.

So I'd like to send request in group of 1K parallel request and when each group completes, do some stuff with the responses(I don't need the responses ordered)

Thanks.

Comment: You should then be using a thread pool with as many threads as you want to have concurrent requests running at any given time. And a CompletableFuture can *runAsync* on a given executor service. Check the last snippet on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52419698/5761558). Just remember to change the pool size from 10 to your desired number of concurrent calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can use completable futures and its done pretty easy.

Let's suppose you have HTTP client that return CompletableFuture on requests.

```java
package com.example.demo.cf;

import com.example.demo.dto.Response;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public interface HttpClient {
    CompletableFuture<Response> makeHttp();
}
```

And have service that batchs and sequences requests.

```java
package com.example.demo.cf;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class CfBatchingService {

    private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 100;

    private HttpClient httpClient;

    public void sendRequests() {
        CompletableFuture<Void> cf = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
        for(int grp = 0; grp < 10; grp++) {
            cf = cf.thenCompose(unused -> CompletableFuture.allOf(IntStream.range(0, BATCH_SIZE).mapToObj(idx -> httpClient.makeHttp()).toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)));
        }

        cf.whenComplete((unused, throwable) -> {
           System.out.println("All requested executed");
        });
    }

}
```

So, the only thing is needed here is to use `thenCompose` method, that expects to get CompletableFuture from lambda.

To group requests into batches and create single `CompletableFuture` you can use method `CompletableFuture.allOf`

Comment: Thank you for you explanation. If I understood, I have to return a CompletableFuture<Response> but If I don't have the java.net.HttpClient class because I'm using JDK8, I think that I have to use another client, right? Thx.

Comment: yep. for example https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client =) or any async http client that return callback. Usually if it's not standard jvm class you can map this callback to completable future.

Comment: In my example its just some kind of HTTP client abstraction with out any implementation. Its not JVM HTTP client.

Comment: Do you know if is there any possibility to get the list of responses after the execution? Because I need to do "things" with them at the end of the process. Thx

Comment: Because If I add the CompletableFuture<Response> to a List and after the process completes, I iterate the list to get the responses, the server closes the connection.